# Access Attribute values of a class

Tags: c#, reflection

This could be very basic..

I have a class

```
[Version("2"), Caching(false)]
class Sample 
{
.....
}
```

How can i access the values of the attributes Version and Caching in C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually isn't that basic. The way to do this is through reflection.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288454%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) is a microsoft tutorial at how to do it.

Reflection an interesting new technology that allows you to see a class as if from the side -> getting access to private and protected fields and functions, as well as attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Accessing Attributes by Using Reflection (C# and Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z919e8tw.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the fasterflect API to do this. It provides extension methods that make reflection tasks like what your describing easy.

http://fasterflect.codeplex.com/

Comment: Adding a whole API is heavy and not useful at all in small projects. Whereas in large projects one doesn't usually add an API to do one task once.

Comment: Worst comment I've seen on stack to date. "adding code to a project is not useful; especially if it solves a problem or performs a function" Classic!

Comment: Adding code is useful. Adding a large bunch of code made by someone else for a one time usage is not. It's heavy, it does not help you learn and it might not fulfull all your needs as they evolve. It's like suggesting to use an I/O library to read a text file once, rather then the standard File.ReadAllLines.

Comment: There is no mention in the author's question of it being a one time deal. You have no clue what the author's is coding or how much of it is based on reflection. All of your unnecessary comments are based on an assumption that doesn't exist with the limited information given.

Comment: I have `a class`. Direct quote. If it was to be reused it would be somewhat more similar to "I want to be able to". But even there, it's preferable to try and get a result without using an API. 1. helps you learn. 2. Isn't heavy.